# Issue in p-autocomplete virtual scroll in primeng 17

Tags: primeng, angular17

I am using latest version of primeng i.e 17. While searching in autocomplete after selection of 2-3 items the size of suggestion panel reduced to almost 0. Still the items are present but they are not properly visible. Any particular solution for this ?

Comment: You are not using PrimeFaces.